# C# Put 0 into the position of an array

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace batesMotel
{


    class Motel
    {
        int[] rooms;
        const int MAX = 21;
        int roomNumber, guests, vacate;

        static void Main()
        {
            Motel BatesMotel = new Motel();
            BatesMotel.runMotel();
            BatesMotel.showAllRooms();



        }
        //*******************************************************
        public Motel()
        {
            rooms = new int[MAX + 1];        // allow rooms from 1 to MAX
        }
        //******************************************************
        public void runMotel()
        {
            string choice = "";
            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("The Bates Motel");
                Console.WriteLine("===============");
                Console.WriteLine("1. Book a room");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Vacate a room");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Display ALL Room Details");
                Console.WriteLine("4. Vacate ALL rooms");
                Console.WriteLine("5. Quit");
                Console.Write("Enter your choice : ");
                choice = Console.ReadLine();
                if (choice == "1")
                {
                    bookRoom();
                }
                else if (choice == "3")
                {

                    showAllRooms();
                }
                else if (choice == "2")
                {
                    vacateOneRoom();
                }
            }
            while (choice != "5");
        }
        //*******************************************************
        public void bookRoom()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("\nThe Bates Motel");
            Console.WriteLine("===============");
            Console.WriteLine("Book a room");
            Console.Write("Enter the room number : ");
            roomNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("How many guests : ");
            guests = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            rooms[roomNumber] = guests;     // make the booking
            Console.WriteLine("Room " + roomNumber + " booked for " + guests + " people");

        }
        //*******************************************************
        public void showAllRooms()
        {

            for (int i = 1; i < MAX; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Room " + (i) + "\t\t\t" + rooms[i] + " guests \n");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
        public void vacateOneRoom()

        {
            int[] nums = new int[21];

            Console.WriteLine("Which room is being vacated");


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Question- I am creating a Hotel project which books people in and also books them out when leaving. I'm struggling on a certain part which asks which room you need vacating and then puts a 0 into this position in the array. I am not going to beat around the bush i don't know where to start. This is my code so far.

Comment: `rooms[indexOfRoomToVacate] = 0;`? `Console.ReadLine()` if you need to read user input from stdin

Comment: Variables should start with a lowercase, so they don't get confused with class names, which start in uppercase. Also, methods should start with an uppercase like `WriteLine()` and `Clear()` from the `Console` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're mixing things up, you need to make the `Motel` class a standalone class, and leave the `Main` method inside the main class (which is `Program` by default). The point here is to make the startup class static and fixed, while the `Motel` would hold the business logic.

```
int[] rooms; 
const int MAX = 21;
int roomNumber, guests, vacate; // unnecessary
```

the array and the constant should be initialized like this :

```
private const int MAX = 21;
private readonly int[] rooms = new int[MAX];
```

the `MAX` is unnecessary as well, you can just set the array directly, but if you need it for readability purpose, then it would be fine.

```
string choice = "";
do
{
    choice = Console.ReadLine();
    if (choice == "1")
    {
        bookRoom();
    }
    else if (choice == "3")
    {

        showAllRooms();
    }
    else if (choice == "2")
    {
        vacateOneRoom();
    }
}
while (choice != "5");
```

two things to consider here :

1. You're expecting an integer, so you will need to validate the input, then convert it to integer.
2. considering that if user enter anything except 5 would be true, this would accept all numbers, letters, and special characters as well. While you only have 5 fixed options (1-5), you need to strict that.

**Naming Convention**

`runMotel`, `bookRoom`, `showAllRooms`, `vacateOneRoom` ! always use Pascal naming convention for properties, methods, classes, and global variables.

For Booking and Vacating, when you asks the user which room number, any number that the user input, you should substitute 1 from it, because the array index starts with 0. For instance, If I need to book room number 21, and you just passed that number to the array index, it would book room 22, so you would need to take 1 from it to get the correct room.

For validating the integer input, you should use `int.TryParse` to validate the input, if it's an integer, it would return true, and the converted value would be out resulted.

I've modified your class :

```
public class Motel
{
    private const int MAX = 21;
    private readonly int[] rooms = new int[MAX];

    private int GetIntegerInput()
    {
        int result;
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Only integers accepted, please try again.");
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void ShowMenu()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("The Bates Motel");
        Console.WriteLine("===============");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Book a room");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Vacate a room");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Display ALL Room Details");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Vacate ALL rooms");
        Console.WriteLine("5. Quit");
        Console.Write("Enter your choice : ");
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        int choice;

        do
        {
            ShowMenu();

            choice = GetIntegerInput();

            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    BookRoom();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    VacateOneRoom();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ShowAllRooms();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    VocateAllRooms();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Only 1 to 5 are allowed.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
            }

        }
        while (true);
    }

    public void BookRoom()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe Bates Motel");
        Console.WriteLine("===============");
        Console.WriteLine("Book a room");
        Console.Write("Enter the room number : ");
        var roomNumber = GetIntegerInput();
        Console.Write("How many guests : ");
        var guests = GetIntegerInput();

        rooms[roomNumber - 1] = guests;     // make the booking

        Console.WriteLine("Room " + roomNumber + " booked for " + guests + " people");

    }

    public void ShowAllRooms()
    {
        Console.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Room " + (i + 1) + "\t\t\t" + rooms[i] + " guests \n");
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    public void VacateOneRoom()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Which room is being vacated");
        var roomNumber = GetIntegerInput();
        rooms[roomNumber - 1] = 0;
    }

    public void VocateAllRooms()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Length; i++)
        {
            rooms[i] = 0;                
        }

    }
}
```

and then you call it from the main method :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Motel BatesMotel = new Motel();
        BatesMotel.Run();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
// int[] rooms; is defined at the top of the class

public void vacateOneRoom()
{
     Console.WriteLine("Which room is being vacated");

     // simple, error prone solution
     rooms[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) + 1] = 0; 
}
```

Comment: I would not use this since it has lots of issues. First of all Console input not validated so Convert may fail. Using " + 1" also a mistake it will over index the array. You need -1. But it is not enough array still can be over indexed.

Comment: I left a comment saying its error prone, but if you look at OP's question code, you can see it's not exactly a production ready code base, it's a set of simple tasks. The real simple answer is: just setting the index of `rooms`.